# How to make a virtual WiFi adapter similar to the bridge option in VM ware linux

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, terminal

What this would look like:

- The Virtual WiFi would have it's own IP
- The Virtual WiFi can be logged onto a different network as the main WiFi
- The Virtual WiFi can be used though a terminal

ps my computer supports virtualization

Comment: `The Virtual WiFi can be logged onto a different network as the main WiFi` – Do you mean a real network, not purely virtual/emulated/etc.? See this: [*Single wifi card, Connect to multiple access points simultaneously*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/328212/108618).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski my computer doesn't support interface combinations but I'm looking for something similar to that